# how to integrate audio with video in android using javacv/opencv?

Tags: android, audio, opencv, ffmpeg, javacv

For my application i created video from set of images by using javacv/opencv in android.but that video plays with out sound.so i want to add my recorded audio(mp3 file) to that generated video how can i achieve it?

This is my code which is used to get video from images,

```
                String path =SCREENSHOT_FOLDER2; 

            File folder = new File(path);


                listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();  
                if(listOfFiles.length>0)
                {









              iplimage = new opencv_core.IplImage[listOfFiles.length];


               for (int j = 0; j < listOfFiles.length; j++) {

                 String files="";       

               if (listOfFiles[j].isFile()) 
               {
               files = listOfFiles[j].getName();

                 }   


                String[] tokens = files.split("\\.(?=[^\\.]+$)");
               String name=tokens[0]; 

                System.out.println(" j " + name);




              iplimage[j]=cvLoadImage("/mnt/sdcard/images/"+name+".png");


               }

            } 



                File videopath = new File(SCREENSHOT_FOLDER3);
                videopath.mkdirs();
                 FFmpegFrameRecord recorder = new          
                    FFmpegFrameRecord(SCREENSHOT_FOLDER3+
                  "video"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".mp4",320,480);

                 try {
                     recorder.setCodecID(CODEC_ID_MPEG4); //CODEC_ID_MPEG4                            
                     //CODEC_ID_MPEG1VIDEO
                     recorder.setBitrate(sampleVideoBitRate);
                     recorder.setFrameRate(10);                     
                     recorder.setPixelFormat(PIX_FMT_YUV420P); //PIX_FMT_YUV420P


                     recorder.start();

                     int x = 0;
                     int y = 0;
                    for (int i=0;i< 300 && x<iplimage.length;i++)

                       {

                         recorder.record(image[x]);

                        if (i>(y+10)) {
                            y=y+1;
                            x++;
                        }

                        }
                     recorder.stop();
                    }
                 catch (Exception e){
                     e.printStackTrace();
                   }
```

now how to integrate audio file(.mp3) file in this code.

Comment: Hey @rams did you find solution of this problem? I'm having same issue.Please answer me over here or email me at robinroya15@gmail.com.

Comment: Anyone who ever wanna know about,How to play the grabbed audio frame from FrameGrabber.

One may look at my blog,Clearly posted what you want,

http://revealedtricks4u.blogspot.in/2015/03/play-audio-sample-grabbed-using-javacv.html

Regards,
Shihab

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV, and subsequently JavaCV has no support for audio.

You have to go with a different library for it. Look at the Android support for video/audio, third-pary libs, or any other way you may find useful.

But don't just expect OpenCV to help you because it's support for audio is 0%.

Comment: Anyone who ever wanna know about,How to play the grabbed audio frame from FrameGrabber.

One may look at my blog,Clearly posted what you want,

http://revealedtricks4u.blogspot.in/2015/03/play-audio-sample-grabbed-using-javacv.html

Regards,
Shihab

Answer (score 0):

I would not say that JavaCV has no support for audio, as it integrates a lot of libraries that opencv does not - ffmpeg for example. Check this long thread for [that issue](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/issues/detail?id=160).

Comment: Anyone who ever wanna know about,How to play the grabbed audio frame from FrameGrabber.

One may look at my blog,Clearly posted what you want,

http://revealedtricks4u.blogspot.in/2015/03/play-audio-sample-grabbed-using-javacv.html

Regards,
Shihab